# excel - autofill top row with weekdays, total, and avg

Tags: excel, date, autofill

I have a tracking document in excel and the top row is a list of weekdays, followed by that week's total, then average. I am trying to autofill this pattern of 5 weekdays + total + avg but am not given the option to only fill weekdays with this pattern.

What I want:

```
4/2/18 - 4/3/18 - 4/4/18 - 4/5/18 - 4/6/18 - Total - Avg - 4/9/18 - 4/10/18 - 4/11/18 - etc
```

What I'm getting:

```
4/2/18 - 4/3/18 - 4/4/18 - 4/5/18 - 4/6/18 - Total - Avg - 4/7/18 - 4/8/18 - 4/9/18 - etc
```

I want to autofill a pattern of 5 weekdays then Total then Avg, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
dim d as long

for d=43192 to 43465    '02-apr-2018 to 31-dec-2018
    select case weekday(d, vbmonday)
        case 6
            cells(1, d-43191) = "total"
        case 7
            cells(1, d-43191) = "avg"
        case else
            cells(1, d-43191) = d
            cells(1, d-43191).numberformat = "m/d/yy"
    end select
next d
```